# What does the regex \S mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

What does /\S/  mean in a regex?

```
while (cur ! = null) {
    if (cur.nodeType == 3 && ! /\S/. test(cur.nodeValue)) {
        element. removeChild(cur);
    } else if (cur. nodeType == 1) {
        cleanWhitespace(cur);
    }
}
```

Comment: For quick reference: `\s` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[ \t\r\n\f]`, whereas `\S` equivals to `[^ \t\r\n\f]`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6507078/1599699

Comment: The spaces between the brackets in @caiosm1005's comment are important. I lost way too much time not realizing that.

Answer (score 240):

`\s` matches whitespace (spaces, tabs and new lines). `\S` is negated `\s`.

Answer (score 85):

`\S` matches anything but a whitespace, according to [this reference](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml).

Comment: what is the front bracket for?

Comment: @steve you mean the backward slash? it's there to *escape* the `S` so as to differentiate it from capital "S"

Comment: @steve The forward slashes in "/\S/" delineate the regular expression.

Answer (score 19):

I believe it means 'anything but a whitespace character'.

Answer (score 9):

`/\S/.test(string)` returns true if and only if there's a non-space character in `string`. Tab and newline count as spaces.

Answer (score -4):

The `\s` [metacharacter](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) matches whitespace characters.

Comment: Attention, it’s case sensitive. This does not answer the original question.

Comment: It's alarming how many upvotes this has