# Replace all whitespace characters

Tags: javascript, trim

I want to replace all occurrences of white space characters (space, tab, newline) in JavaScript.
How to do so?

I tried:

```
str.replace(/ /gi, "X")
```

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: What is "X" and why?

Comment: What about string.replace('',"X");

Comment: its just for an example @MuhammadShahzad ;)

Answer (score 371, accepted):

You want [`\s`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

> Matches a single white space
>   character, including space, tab, form
>   feed, line feed.

Equivalent to

```
[ \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]
```

in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-white-space) and `[ \f\n\r\t\v]` in [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

---

```
str = str.replace(/\s/g, "X");
```

Comment: +1 for remembering to show that the `replace` function doesn't modify `str`, so you have to assign it back.

Comment: In a function, you can return str.replace, so you don't need to assign in that scope.

Comment: Remember for R to use `perl = TRUE`, like `gsub(pattern = "[\\s]+", ..., perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 48):

We can also use this if we want to change all multiple joined blank spaces with a single character:

```
str.replace(/\s+/g,'X');
```

See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/d9d53G/1

**Explanation**

> / `\s+` / g

- `\s+` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
- `+` **Quantifier** — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

- **Global pattern flags**

  - *g modifier: g*lobal. All matches (don't return after first match)

Comment: The regex plus (+) is useful for my use case where I'm replacing whitespace type characters with an underscore (_) and if my users fat finger an extra space I really don't want to display an extra _.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 38):

`\s` is a meta character that covers all white space. You don't need to make it case-insensitive — white space doesn't have case.

```
str.replace(/\s/g, "X")
```

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried the `\s`?

```
str.replace(/\s/g, "X");
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use

```
str.replace(/\s/g, "");
```

it replaces all whitespaces. For example:

```
var str = "hello my world";
str.replace(/\s/g, "") //the result will be "hellomyworld"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/\s/g, "X")
```

Comment: That doesn’t work. `\s\n\t` matches: any whitespace character, followed by a newline, followed by tab.

Answer (score 3):

Not /gi but /g

```
var fname = "My Family File.jpg"
fname = fname.replace(/ /g,"_");
console.log(fname);
```

gives

```
"My_Family_File.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it has been worked  but

just try this.

take the value /\s/g into a string variable like

```
String a = /\s/g;

str = str.replaceAll(a,"X");
```

Comment: where did you get `replaceAll` from?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `trim`

`let str = '    Hello World      ';`

`alert (str.trim());`

All the front and back spaces around Hello World would be removed.

Comment: This would remove the whitespaces between "hello" and "world". Question says "all" whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

I've used the "slugify" method from underscore.string and it worked like a charm:

https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#slugifystring--string

The cool thing is that you can really just import this method, don't need to import the entire library.