# How to send scraped revenue data to my tool?

Tags: javascript, dom, web-scraping, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

Because a client doesn't have a dataLayer I'm trying to send scraped revenue data from a thank you page to a Facebook pixel that's being deployed through GTM.

I have `Imdocument.querySelectorAll("td")[8].textContent` from another useful post but its giving me a string, with spaces and currency symbol.

```
"
                        $65.00
                    "
```

[Image of the dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBUv1.png)
[Image of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3izqT.jpg)

How can I **only** get revenue data w/o currency symbol? Just a number.

Answer (score 0):

Just use .replace(" ","") and all the spaces should be replaced.

Comment: This will remove a single space character. It won't remove tabs or other whitespace characters, and will not touch the currency sign. For whitespace removal see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507056/replace-all-whitespace-characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract float digit from string with regexp `/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g`. In your case it will be like this:

```
var str = Imdocument.querySelectorAll("td")[8].textContent;
var price = str.match(/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g)[0];
```