# How to remove whitespace in text

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, trim

How can I trim a text string in my Angular application?

Example

```
{{ someobject.name }}
```

someobject.name results in "name abc"

What I like to achieve is name to be "nameabc" 
(remove all whitespaces).

I already created a pipe and included this in the typescript file and module)

PIPE:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: 'trim' })
export class TrimPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any) {
        if (!value) {
            return '';
        }

        return value.trim();
    }
}
```

{{ someobject.name | trim }} still results in "name abc" instead of "nameabc" }}

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the docs, the trim() method removes *trailing* and *leading* whitespaces, not those in the middle.

https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

If you want to remove all whitespaces use the `replace` function:

```
"name abc".replace(/\s/g, "");
```

Comment: I would use `/\s*/g` to increase performance, but upvote for you anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.How do I use this in my pipe/edit my pipe.

Comment: Exactly like you do now, just use ``replace`` instead of ``trim`` when returning from your ``transform`` function

Comment: thanks I already fixed it before reading this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

trim() only removes whitespaces from the start and end of a string:

https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

have a look here to remove whitespaces between strings:

[Replace all whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507056/replace-all-whitespace-characters)

the relevant part is to use it like:

```
str = str.replace(/\s/g, "X");
```

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered ideal at SO. They can die and rot. Please include the relevant information here, in your post.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'removeWhiteSpace'
})
export class RemoveWhiteSpacePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): any {
    if (value === undefined)
      return 'undefined';
    return value.replace(/\s/g, "");
  }

}
```

Comment: You should explain why the OP solution doesn't work and how yours works

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-remove-spaces

Here's a implementation of @Nirav's solution

Answer (score 0):

*Replace all the whitespace between string*

`let spaceReg = new RegExp(" ",'g');`

`let str = "name abc"`

`str = str.replace(spaceReg,"");`

Answer (score -11):

In my case this is bad:

```
<div>
  {{ someobject.name }}
</div>
```

Solution:

```
<div>{{ someobject.name}}</div>
```

=S

Comment: This doesn't appear to be related to the question. They want to remove whitespace inside a result of a variable, not avoid whitespace around it...

Comment: This is not a related answer. Understand the question then answer.