# How to replace white space between strings in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

My requirement is to replace empty spaces between strings which i mentioned below.The strings are seperated by |

String1=Location:New York|Enterprise:Apple Inc

Expected outcome String1=Location:NewYork|Enterprise:AppleInc
What needs to be given inside the replace function as \s is considered as character s

Comment: So something like `myString.replace(/ /g, '');`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace all whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507056/replace-all-whitespace-characters)

Comment: @Beller inside the bracket for the character to be replaced we should provide inside a quotes right?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use something like:

```
String1.replaceAll(' ', '');
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Comment: ReplaceAll function is not available in typescript.Replace is available but it replaces only the first instance