# How can I remove all whitespace in Zod?

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

According to the docs of Zod I can use trim, but trim will only remove the whitespace characters at the end and beginning. I am looking for a way to remove all of the whitespace characters. To give you an idea of the setup I am using (removed irrelevant code):

```
const stp = zodString({
    invalid_type_error: '',
    required_error: '',
}).trim()
    .min(1, { message: '' })
    .max(10, { message: '' })
    .regex(reg, { message: '', });
```

Is there a way to implement some sort of trim to remove all white space with zodString?

Comment: "Trimming space" in the middle of a string is odd. Could you provide sample data demonstrating this? I can see compacting multiple spaces into one space.

Comment: Well for example, you just wrote "Trimming space". I wish to have the white character in between "Trimming space" removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace all whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507056/replace-all-whitespace-characters)

Comment: Wouldn't you just need `z.string().regex(/^\S+$/);`

Comment: @isherwood No, because that would be done outside of the zodstring function. I am looking for a built-in way with zodString to resolve this.

Comment: @SouvikDey No, unfortunately it doesn;t.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a pipe, you can first remove the white spaces and then perform additional validations.

```
z.string().transform(value => value.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
.pipe(z.string().min(1, { message: 'This field is required' }))
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `.trim()` you used in the code snippet will remove the whitespaces from both ends of the string.

If for some reason you want to filter all whitespaces use `.transform()`

```
z.string().transform(value => value.replaceAll(" ", ""))
```

Comment: Is this possible with zodString? I cannot change the setup.

Comment: "transform is not a function" whenever I use your answer.

Comment: What is `zodString`? where did you import from? there is a `ZodString` class with uppercase Z that returns a ZodString instance which includes `.transform`. What about `zodString`?

Comment: I changed the code to z.string as well. Still not capturing it. I can update the OP so you can see it for yourself. All I am looking for is the original post code (can even be with z.string) to have all the white characters removed.

Comment: [`.transform`](https://zod.dev/?id=transform) is a method for `z.string()` that takes a function as argument. this function takes a parameter (value: string) and must return the new/modified value.

Comment: I have: z.string().transfrom(value => value.replaceAll(" ", "")) and it throws the error "transform is not a function". I imported z from zod as well. Do I need to import transform as well?

Comment: What is your zod version in `package.json`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255329/discussion-between-i-try-so-hard-but-i-cry-harder-and-ahmed-abdelbaset).

Answer (score -3):

Zod provides a `refine` method that you can use to apply custom validation and transformations to the data. In your case, you can use this method to remove all whitespace characters from the string. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```js
const stp = zodString({
  invalid_type_error: '',
  required_error: '',
})
  .refine((data) => typeof data === 'string', {
    message: 'Invalid input, not a string',
  })
  .refine(
    (data) => {
      // Remove all whitespace characters
      return data.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    },
    {
      message: 'String contains whitespace characters',
    }
  )
  .min(1, {
    message: 'String is too short',
  })
  .max(10, {
    message: 'String is too long',
  })
  .regex(reg, {
    message: 'String does not match the regex',
  });
```

This way, you can achieve the desired behavior of removing all whitespace characters using Zod.

Comment: This is wrong. `refine` does **not** apply transformations.