# Double \\ in regular expression iOS

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

Does anyone understand what this `(([A-Za-z\\s])+)\\?` means?
I wonder why it should be `"\\s"` and `"\\"` ?

If I entered `"\s"`, Xcode just doesn't understand and if I entered `"\?"`, it just doesn't match the `"?"`.

I have googled a lot, but I did not find a solution. Anyone knows?

Comment: sorry it's  (([A-Za-z\\s])+)\\?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual regex is `(([A-Za-z\s])+)\?`. This matches one or more letters and whitespace characters followed by an question mark. The `\` has two different meanings here. In the first instance `\s` has a fixed meaning and stands for any white space characters. In the second instance the `\?` means the literal question mark character. The escaping is necessary as the question mark means one or none of the previous otherwise.

You can't type your regex like this in a string literal in C code though. C also does some escaping using the backslash character. For example `"\n"` is translated to a string containing only a newline character. There are some other escape sequences with special meanings. If the character after the backslash doesn't have a special meaning the backslash is just removed. That means if you want to have a single backspace in your string you have to write two.

So if you wrote your regex string as you wanted you'd get different results as it would be interpreted as  `(([A-Za-zs])+)?` which has a completely different meaning. So when you write a regex in an ObjC (or any other C-based language) string literal you must double all backslash characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It bothers me a whole day . Your explaination

Comment: Your explanation is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

not sure about ios but same thing happens in java. `\` is escape character for java,and c also so when you type `\s` java reads \ as an escape character.

think of it as if you want to print a `\` what will you have to do.
you will have to type `\\`. now first \ will work as escape character for java and second one will be printed.

I think it should be the same concept for ios too.

so if you want \s you type \s, if you want \ you type \\.

Answer (score -4):

The `\s` metacharacter is used to find a whitespace character.

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377480/what-does-this-s-regex-mean-in-javascript/30773657#30773657)!