# How Javascript breaks up a piece of text into individual words? and add span tags to each word?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I wrote a piece of JavaScript code and want to implement two functions:

1: *Break a piece of text into separate word arrays.*
So far, I have used `regex` to search for spaces and punctuation. It does part of the functionality, but can't do anything about the whitespace code `&nbsp;`.

2: Wrap each word in the HTML with a `span` tag. (I don't know how should I implement this)

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var text = document.getElementById('text').textContent
            // Regex cannot search for `&nbsp;`
        var word_array = text.split(/[ \t\n\r.?,"';:!()[\]{}<>\/]/)
        console.log(text)
        console.log(word_array)
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body> 
    the other text
    <div id="text">
        this is
        text,break&nbsp;up&nbsp;&nbsp;the;words!
        istest testis,
        text <a href="#">text build</a> html tag! 
    </div>
    the other text
</body>

</html>
```

However, my code does not separate the three words. For example, `break&nbsp;up&nbsp;&nbsp;the`, should become to `[break,up,the]`.

Also, I didn't wrap all the words in the div with `span` tags, like this:

```html
<div id="text">
<span id='word_1'>this</span> <span id='word_2'>is</span>
...
<span id='word_3'>text</span> <a href="#"><span id='word_4'>text</span> <span id='word_5'>build</span></a> <span id='word_6'>html</span> <span id='word_7'>tag</span>!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`\s`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4377480/5041759) will do the job. You can change:

```
var word_array = text.split(/[ \t\n\r.?,"';:!()[\]{}<>\/]/)
                              ^^
```

to:

```
var word_array = text.split(/[\s\t\n\r.?,"';:!()[\]{}<>\/]/)
                              ^^
```

By the way, `\s` is a [shorthand](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[ \t\r\n\f]`. So you can simplify your expression to:

```
var word_array = text.split(/[\s.?,"';:!()[\]{}<>\/]/)
```

Then you may need to remove empty elements from array:

```
//remove '' from word_array
var word_array2 = word_array.filter(e => e != '')
```

For the question 2, following code will wrap the text words with `span` tag:
Edited based on the comment of [`@dong`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17827912/dong)

```
function add_span(word_array, element_) {
    for (let i = 0; i < word_array.length; i++) {
        var reg = new RegExp("([\s.?,\"';:!(){}<>])(" + word_array[i] + ")([\s.?,\"';:!])", 'g');
        element_ = element_.replace(reg, '$1<span>$2</span>$3');
    }
    return element_
}
```

Comment: Can I add `&nbsp;` to my original regular expression instead of replacing it with spaces?

Comment: yes, you can with `\s` metacharacter which renders whitespace. Please check the updated answer

Comment: awesome! Regular expression problem solved.
For the second problem of wrapping all words in span tags, your code removes the html tags from the original code (eg <a href="#">text build</a>).
I solved it according to your idea.
```
function add_span(word_array, element_){
  for (let i=0; i<word_array.length; i++) {
  var reg = new RegExp("([\s.?,\"';:!(){}<>])(" + word_array[i] + ")([\s.?,\"';:!])", 'g');
  element_ = element_.replace(reg,'$1<span>$2</span>$3');
  }
  return element_
}
```